# Handbrake & FFMpeg Encoding Performance: M1 vs M1 Pro (older M1 is faster) - Why?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, performance, handbrake

The older and slower M1 MacMini is 2 to 2.5x faster currently on the same tasks using the latest and same versions of HandBrake or FFmpeg (with M1 patch for VideoToolBox) as compared to the M1 Pro 2021 MacBook 14"

This is the result when using the VideoToolBox encoder for hardware acceleration (both H264 and HEVC)

MacMini - M1 with 8GB RAM / 256GB SSD
MacBook Pro 14" - 16GB RAM / 512GB SSD

Seems like there is some optimization or instruction patches that need to be done for the M1 Pro (and M1 Max) in comparison to the M1.

Just found that to be interesting that something is different in that processing pipeline and requires explicit code change in order to support the newer processors vs just working.

Am I missing something or have some obvious issue.

All tests were done using the exact same input files with the same encode parameters for output on both machines.

(YES I know the VideoToolBox encodes are not of the same quality / size efficiency as the x264 / x265 software non hardware accelerated library - but for my purpose I prefer the time savings when using VideoToolBox).

Thanks for any explanation / pointers / clarifications / etc.

Comment: Tell us how the executables and libraries you're using were compiled. What compiler version? What compiler flags?